# Symfony 3.4 Doctrine : The association refers to the inverse side field which is not defined as association

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

Entity\Recognition

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="c_rcgntn")
 */
class Recognition {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\RecognitionType", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_recogtype_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $recogType;
```

Entity\RecognitionType

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="c_rcgntn_type")
 */
class RecognitionType {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Recognition",mappedBy="recogType")
     */
    protected $id;
```

When running this in my dev environment, I see the errors show up in my profiler. It isn't a big issue as the code still runs and returns the joins properly. I just can't shake the error.

> The association Entity\Recognition#recogType refers to the
>   inverse side field Entity\RecognitionType#id which is not
>   defined as association. The association
>   Entity\Recognition#recogType refers to the inverse side
>   field Entity\RecognitionType#id which does not exist.

Comment: I removed the inversedBy and the error went away.

Comment: Your `RecognitionType` class is not written as on the documentation. Please see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional for Unidirectional Association Mapping or http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional for Bidirectional Association Mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the definition of the "**id**" field in **RecognitionType** with the relation to Recognition entity. From **RecognitionType** remove line:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Recognition",mappedBy="recogType")
```

That should be enough for a unidirectional relation, your definition of **recogType** field is enough for it.

If you want to add the relation in RecognitionType also, then add a new field to it:

```
/**
 * ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Recognition", mappedBy="recogType")
 */
protected $recognition;
```

Note that no schema update is required after the above definition.